# Accuracy doesn't improve in training model character recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am building a training model for my character recognition system. During every epochs, I am getting the same accuracy and it doesn't improve. I have currently 4000 training images and 77 validation images.
My model is as follows:

```py
inputs = Input(shape=(32,32,3))
x = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu')(inputs)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = Conv2D(filters = 32,        
kernel_size = 3,            
activation = 'relu')(x)  
x = MaxPooling2D()(x) 
x = Flatten()(x) 
x=Dense(256,
activation='relu')(x)
outputs = Dense(1, activation = 'softmax')(x) 
model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs) 
model.compile(
optimizer='adam', 
loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
metrics=['accuracy']) 
data_gen_train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

data_gen_test=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

data_gen_valid = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

train_generator = data_gen_train.flow_from_directory(directory=r"./drive/My Drive/train_dataset", 
target_size=(32,32), batch_size=10, class_mode="binary")

valid_generator = data_gen_valid.flow_from_directory(directory=r"./drive/My 
                  Drive/validation_dataset", target_size=(32,32), batch_size=2, class_mode="binary")

test_generator = data_gen_test.flow_from_directory(
                 directory=r"./drive/My Drive/test_dataset",
                 target_size=(32, 32),

                 batch_size=6,
                 class_mode="binary"
)
model.fit(
train_generator,
epochs =10, 
steps_per_epoch=400,
validation_steps=37,
validation_data=valid_generator)
```

The result is as follows:

> ```
> Found 4000 images belonging to 2 classes.
> Found 77 images belonging to 2 classes.
> Found 6 images belonging to 2 classes.
> Epoch 1/10
> 400/400 [==============================] - 14s 35ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5811
> Epoch 2/10
> 400/400 [==============================] - 13s 33ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5811
> Epoch 3/10
> 400/400 [==============================] - 13s 34ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5676
> Epoch 4/10
> 400/400 [==============================] - 13s 33ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5676
> Epoch 5/10
> 400/400 [==============================] - 18s 46ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5541
> Epoch 6/10
> 400/400 [==============================] - 13s 34ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5676
> Epoch 7/10
> 400/400 [==============================] - 13s 33ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5676
> Epoch 8/10
> 400/400 [==============================] - 13s 33ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5946
> Epoch 9/10
> 400/400 [==============================] - 13s 33ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5811
> Epoch 10/10
> 400/400 [==============================] - 13s 33ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5811
> <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fa3a5f4a8d0>
> ```

Comment: The last dense layer has dimension 1. It seems you're trying to do binary classification. You may try loss='binary_crossentropy'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to recognize charaters of 2 classes, you should:

- use `class_mode="binary"` in the `flow_from_directory` function
- use `binary_crossentropy` as loss
- your last layer must have 1 neuron with `sigmoid` activation function

In case there are more than 2 classes:

- do not use `class_mode="binary"` in the `flow_from_directory` function
- use `categorical_crossentropy` as loss
- your last layer must have *n* neurons with `softmax` activation, where *n* stands for the number of classes